# Modify existing BitmapImage in memory

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

My WinRT XAML page loads an image from a file asset like this:

```
Image img = new Image();  // Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Image
BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage(new Uri(Page.BaseUri, "Assets/myImage.png"));
img.Source = bmp;
```

So far so good. Now, at a later time, I'd like to do some transformations such as resizing and cropping.

It looks like this can be [done](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj709937.aspx) using [BitmapEncoder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.graphics.imaging.bitmapencoder.aspx) and [BitmapTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.graphics.imaging.bitmapencoder.bitmaptransform.aspx), but will require reading and writing to disk - in particular, writing out the modified image to a new file.

Since my app does potentially do many transformations, I'd prefer to do this in memory without any disk I/O but can't figure out how.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the `WriteableBitmap` class, this allows modifications in memory.

```
WriteableBitmap bmi2 = new WriteableBitmap(bitmapSource);
```

More infomation can be found here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/BR243259